# Altium Plug Card

Tags: pcb, altium, footprint, gerber

I am new to Altium and I need some help. I am trying to make a pretty simple card and need to use Altium to make the gerber files that I can send to a pcb maker. I need to make the card using this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vector-electronics/3662/V1016-ND/38881. I have tried to make this myself with nothing but frustration.

Edit:
I am not familiar with Altium. I have a gerber file for the board that I have linked but I need to edit the file to have leads and pads connected to certain connectors. I was asking for help importing that board into Altium so I could just make the connections and mark where I would be attaching the power supply I need to mount to the board. I am having problems with Altium. I need to do this to send the new board to a pcb maker that wants them in an Altium file.

Can This just be deleted?

Comment: `I have tried to make this myself with nothing but frustration` ... this is a totally useless description of the problems that you ran into ... please describe the problems that you ran into ..... also, what do you expect the PCB manufacturer to do with the card that you mentioned in your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to make the card using this [link to Vector proto-board]".  What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: And your question is.....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
If you are new in Altium you have to know basics. Here you have short lessons from altium. It help you create simple schematic and pcb designs [Altium Lessons](https://go.altium.com/AD-evaluation-guide-1-projects-and-environment.html). In my opinion you can immediatley design pcb without schematic because you need only pads. You can add a lot of pads (Placa -> Pad -> (Optionaly Tab for options)) and align it. I'm not sure what is the problem couse therefore i gave you toutorials.

Comment: Don't use vias in place of pads. Use actual pads (Place -> Pad)

Comment: You're right. My mistake. Sorry

Comment: No worries, and no need to apologize. My predecessor at work just always used vias instead of free pads and it drove me absolutely insane. They're treated differently in Altium.

Comment: Yeah. I understand you. I thought about pads and i wrote a via. Tiredness... :)